# Xcode 4.5: How to know which orientation you are currently in by looking at the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I am currently using Xcode 4.5, and I wanted to know how can we determine which orientation we are currently in by looking at the simulator?

Previously, there was a home button in the simulator which let you know which orientation you were in:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, or
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

But, I dont know how that can be done in the latest versions of the simulator.
What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I wanted to know how to determine the orientation just by looking at the Simulator, programatically, its very much possible.

Here is a snapshot which I see whenever I launch the Simulator for iPad:

[image: iPad Simulator ScreenShot]

For iPhone Retina

[image: iPhone Retina Simulator]

For iPhone

[image: iPhone]

I checked out the options by, I could not see how we know whether the Simulator is in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, except in the Case of iPhone.

I could not find the same for iPad and iPhone Retina Simulators.

Programatically, its possible as mentioned in one of the answers, but I wanted to know if there was a way to find this out while checking the Simulator itself.

What could be I missing?

Comment: The home button is still there.

Comment: You can use your eyes.

Comment: In simulator Goto Hardware -> change device type you will get Back button

Comment: Why do you actually want to know that?

Comment: @MarcMosby I wanted to know if it was possible to know this and if I was missing something or I did not know something very basic which could be done in the Simulator itself.

Comment: Well if you have the iPad in your hand and hide the cam/home button you don't know it either ;)

Comment: @MarcMosby In device ofcourse, its obvious, just thought I may not know about the same thing for the Simulator.. :)